# Request DTO not getting populated with PATCH request containing "multipart/form-data"

Tags: servicestack

i have the following `patch` request:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://localhost:8888/image' \
--form 'Width=1500' \
--form 'Height=1000' \
--form 'ID=5f3c03457118797a3a7a6f8c' \
--form 'File=@/D:/IMG_20190901_144155.jpg'
```

my request DTO looks like this:

```cs
    [Route("/image")]
    public class Request : IReturnVoid
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
```

service method looks like this:

```cs
    public class ImageService : Service
    {
        public async Task Patch(Request req)
        {
            var id = req.ID;
            var height = req.Height;
            var width = req.Width;

            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
```

the problem i'm having is the request DTO does not get populated by servicestack.

if i place a breakpoint and inspect in debug the `Servicestack.Web.IRequest.FormData` property, it shows the following exception:

> '((ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest)Request).FormData' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException'

however, if i simply change it to a `POST` request instead of `PATCH` everything works just fine.

is this a bug in servicestack or am i missing something crucial here?

if you need a repro project, you can find it [here](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoWebApiStarter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a bug in servicestack which has now been resolved with [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/0fc6dd94a5cea2022cc66a4148ccc9dad1fb67b9) commit.